# Multiple Text Fields With One Type Of Query Parameter in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2007, query-string

My form has multiple Input Text Boxes. To keep it simple; I need to search the database field with user inputted text. Example:

- Contains the term "bus" (in text box 1)
- and "tracks" (in text box 2)
- and "route" (in text box3).

When I hit the "Search" button the result should be populated.

Right now I am using this for one text area input

My query is:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![ATG]![ContainsSearch] & "*"
```

Comment: got the solution thanks....SELECT ATG1.Term
FROM ATG1
WHERE ((((ATG1.Term) Like "*" & [Forms]![ContainsForm]![ContainsText] & "*" Or (ATG1.Term) Like "*" & [Forms]![ContainsForm]![ContainsText1] & "*") And ((ATG1.Term) Not Like "*" & [Forms]![ContainsForm]![NotContainsText] & "*" Or (ATG1.Term) Not Like "*" & [Forms]![ContainsForm]![NotContainsText1] & "*")));

Comment: @user823911, thanks for putting the answer here too, but it really should go into the _Answer_ field, so someone else can find it in the future. Hopefully enough time has passed for you to answer your own question by now. (Plus, it can be _legible_ in an answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP provided answer is as follows (starting community wiki)

```
SELECT ATG1.Term 
   FROM ATG1 
WHERE 
 (
   (
     (
         (ATG1.Term) Like "" & [Forms]![ContainsForm]![ContainsText] &  "" Or 
         (ATG1.Term) Like "" & [Forms]![ContainsForm]![ContainsText1] & ""
     ) And 
     (
         (ATG1.Term) Not Like "" & [Forms]![ContainsForm]![NotContainsText] & "" Or
         (ATG1.Term) Not Like "" & [Forms]![ContainsForm]![NotContainsText1] & ""
     )
   )
 );
```